# Beautifulsoup gets elements not selected in the soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, foreach, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website listed in the code and in the data i have selected a specific div/class, however it seems to return anything that starts with "product". Could you please help me with this code. Appreciate your help for a newbie in Python. Also if this can be written better i will gladly take it.

```
url="https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-tas-regional-glenorchy/everything/browse/dairy--eggs-meals/milk-3796059?pageNumber="
for x in range(1,6):
turl=url+str(x)
driver.get(turl)
time.sleep(10)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product"})
t=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "product-brand"]')
count=0
maxC=int(len(t))
for item in data:
    if count < maxC and count>=0:
        if item.find("span", {"class":"product-brand"}) is not None:
            ProductText1=item.find("span", {"class":"product-brand"}).text
        else:
            ProductText1=""
        if item.find("span", {"class":"product-name"}) is not None:
            ProductText2=item.find("span", {"class":"product-name"}).text
        else:
            ProductText2=""
        if item.find("span", {"class":"package-size"}) is not None:
            size=item.find("span", {"class":"package-size"}).text
        else:
            size=""            
        if item.find("span", {"class":"package-price"}).text is not None:
            Price=item.find("span", {"class":"package-price"}).text
        else:
            Price=""
        if item.find("span", {"class":"product-qty"}).text is not None:
            Price1=item.find("span", {"class":"product-qty"}).text
        else:
            Price1=""
        if item.find("span", {"class":"product-price"}).text is not None:
            Price2=item.find("span", {"class":"product-qty"}).text
        else:
            Price2=""
        ProductText=str(ProductText1)+" "+str(ProductText2)
        writer.writerow([ProductText,Price2,size,Price])
    count+=1
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation. It probably got lost when you copy-pasted the code. It is very important in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider extracting the json containing all that info from the ajax request url. I read the specified items into a dataframe but you can treat as required.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://shop.coles.com.au/online/a-tas-regional-glenorchy/dairy--eggs-meals/milk-3796059?tabType=everything&tabId=everything&personaliseSort=false&orderBy=20512_6&errorView=AjaxActionErrorResponse&requesttype=ajax&beginIndex=0'

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-colrs-transformer]")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'lxml')
d.quit()

item = soup.select_one('[data-colrs-transformer]')
data= json.loads(item.text)
products = data['products']
items = [[product['m'] ,product['n'] ,product['a']['O3'][0],product['u2'], product['a']['A4'][0],product['p1']['o']] for product in products]
df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = ['brand', 'productName', 'packageSize', 'packagePrice', 'productQty', 'productPrice'])
print(df)
```

---

**Example of JSON structure:**

[image]

---

To calculate the number of pages of results and therefore the required offset values for the ajax

```
import math
itemsPerPage  = data['searchInfo']['pageSize']
totalItems = data['searchInfo']['totalCount']
numPages = math.ceil(totalItems/itemsPerPage)
offsetStart = 0
for i in range(2 ,numPages + 1):
    offsetStart += itemsPerPage
    print(offsetStart)
```

Comment: Awesome. This is gold. I totally loved the way you presented this. Thanks

Comment: Pleasure. Any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you able to shed some light as to how i can loop through all pages? The Ajax obviously give the JSON for current page. One way i found was to increment the begin index by 48, but that's not ideal as number of pages changes as i go into different product categories. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I will have a look today.

Comment: I can see a little one potential way. Do you have another URL so I can test transferable solution might be.

Comment: https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-tas-regional-glenorchy/everything/browse/dairy--eggs-meals/dairy-eggs?pageNumber=1

Comment: This has 14 pages without a next button

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate it.

Comment: No worries. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Feel better

Comment: QHarr - did you get a chance on this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry fpr delay. I have updated answer. You then just need a loop using those offset values.

Comment: You are welcome. Once again, thank you for your patience.